# Data Base Model - Huge (over 1 million lines) text files

Tags: php, python, perl, database-design

I have to work on a project involving huge amount of data stored in a raw text file. Each field is delimited by its size, ie, field 1 is from position 0 to 3, etc.. (not CSV file)

The file contains over a million lines.

I need to store it into a database. I checked several posts about what would be the best way to go about it, and it seems like the technology choice matters less than the algorithm. I'm open to Php, Perl or Python. Feel free to suggest anything.

Now, the file structure in itself is a bit tricky. Here is an example:

```
A880780093vvd47aa8db20d4133e6f587cf046054e8316000212093659D11001 
C880780093d47aa8db20d4133e6f587cf046054e831600021209365907000 0711012012C    
A880780093vvcaacb22bfb091127f9c9e14175d858ee25000212093681O11001 
C880780093caacb22bfb091127f9c9e14175d858ee2500021209368107000 0611012012ADI  
D880780093caacb22bfb091127f9c9e14175d858ee250002120936810700011012012HK00210Z            
A880780093vvb92f937a3fd1268c1478deb174a1bfca86000212093750S11041 
C880780093b92f937a3fd1268c1478deb174a1bfca8600021209375007000 3911012012PB   
C880780093b92f937a3fd1268c1478deb174a1bfca8600021209375007000 3911012012B 1002
E880780093212093750b92f937a3fd1268c1478deb174a1bfca8600007000110120120100000127000000000000
C880780093b92f937a3fd1268c1478deb174a1bfca8600021209375007000 3911012012B
```

Basically, there are 6 types of lines, from A to F; line A is the header of the block. Lines B and C have the exact same length and fields. Line D is a possible complement to line C, meaning that it is attached to a line C but not required; also meaning there cannot be a line D without a line C. Lines E and F are independent lines, only attached to line A. (all lines are part of a block, so they could all be "attached" to a line A, or a virtual block ID)

How would I go about to create a model that would allow me to:
- modify some data on some lines based on some criteria (ie, if 5th char of line C is 4, then 10th becomes 7)
- keep track of the modified ones (ie, I want to be able to link them to their original selves)
- Be able to rebuild the original text file, deleting the original lines and replacing them by their modified version
- Be able to insert new lines in the block: if line C has 7th char = 0 then I add below it a D line.
- keep the line order intact. (if one line is inserted, it moves the order for the following line by  1 rank ahead)

I thought about using a parent_id foreign key in all 5 line tables (one per each line type, since they do not have the same fields); thus resolving the line ordering issue, but I am stuck at rebuilding the modified file version. I also thought about dividing the file into blocks (starting by a line A), then linking lines to block ID...

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Ha, what is big, what is not in our days?

Comment: I believe this is too complex to ask here with vague requirements. Perhaps you could rephrase your question in more specific smaller parts? I don't really care to design and implement your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the file line by line and use a stack. Something along the lines:

```
<?php

// You'd have to implement the database yourself!
$db = new Database();
$db->startTransaction();

$stack = array();
$fh    = fopen("my-file", "r");
$i     = 0;
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
  if (!isset($buffer[0])) {
    continue;
  }

  switch ($buffer[0]) {
    case "A":
      // Do something ...
      break;

    case "C":
      // Do something ...
      break;

    case "C":
      if ($stack[$i] != "C") {
        trigger_error("Line D without preceding line C");
      }
      // Do something ...
      break;

     // More stuff ...
  }

  $stack[$i++] = $buffer;
  $db->insert("INSERT INTO table (line) VALUES ($buffer)");
}

$db->commitTransaction();

?>
```

Of course there are better solutions than the ugly `switch`, but it's quick'n'dirty. Your database design answer is impossible to answer because we have no clue about the requirements. All in all consider posting **your** work and ask specific questions regarding a small piece of a big problem and not asking to solve big problems.